# Executing Equation through multi raster using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, error-000732

I am trying to execute this equation through multi raster, but i am getting error massage in TScalar2 function, error message shown here

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\Arc-GIS-Python-Script\T_SCALAR.py    23      
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset Mean_Temp_010.tif does not exist or is not supported
```

). Below i have attached my code.

```
import arcpy, os, calendar
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
topWorkspace = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2'
ws_out = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\TScalar' ### Output folder!!!
arcpy.env.workspace = topWorkspace

# Get dict of months and month-number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)
months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} # Get dict of months and month number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)


# Step through list of all folders
for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
    baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
    if baseName in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
        monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

        # Raster1 take Mean_Temp raster from all month folder(e.g for january: 001_Mean_temp.tif) and Raster 2 is constant month of october raster
        rasterList1 = arcpy.ListRasters('*Mean_Temp.tif')
        rasterList2 = arcpy.Raster('*Mean_Temp_010.tif')

        # combine list raster into equation
        TScalar1 = 1.1814 / (1+Exp(0.2 * (rasterList2 - 10 - rasterList1)))
        TScalar2 = 1 / (1+Exp(0.3 * (- rasterList2 - 10 + rasterList1)))

        if len(rasterList) > 1:

        #Print raster list
         #print rasterList

        # Multiply of TScalar1 and TScalar2 rasters 
         TScalar = (TScalar1 * TScalar2)

        #Save the output
        outRasterName = os.path.join(ws_out, "T_SCALAR_{}.tif".format(monthNumber))
        TScalar.save(outRasterName)
        print outRasterName


#print done
print 'done'
```

Updated code shown here along with error massage

```
Message File Name   Line    Position
        Traceback
            <module>    D:\Arc-GIS-Python-Script\T_SCALAR.py    27
            Minus   C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py 3840
            swapper C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py 47
            wrapper C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py 3837
        TypeError: expected a raster or layer name

    import arcpy, os, calendar
    from arcpy.sa import *
    from arcpy import env
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
    topWorkspace = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2'
    ws_out = r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\TScalar' ### Output folder!!!
    arcpy.env.workspace = topWorkspace
    # Get dict of months and month-number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)
    months = {calendar.month_name[i].upper(): str(i).zfill(3) for i in range(1, 13)} # Get dict of months and month number (i.e. January = 001, March = 003 etc.)


    # Step through list of all folders
    for folderPath in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
        baseName = os.path.basename(folderPath).upper()
        if baseName in months: # Test that subfolder is a month name
            monthNumber = months[baseName] # Get month-number for use in output filename
            arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath

            # Raster1 take Mean_Temp raster from all month folder(e.g for january: Mean_temp_001.tif) and Raster 2 is constant month of october raster
            rasterList1 = arcpy.ListRasters(r'Mean_Temp*.tif')
            rasterList2 = arcpy.Raster(r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\OCTOBER\Mean_Temp_010.tif')


            # combine list raster into equation
            TScalar1 = 1.1814 / ((1 + Exp(0.2 * (rasterList2 - 10 - rasterList1))))
            TScalar2 = 1 / (1 + Exp(0.3 * (- rasterList2 - 10 - rasterList1)))

            #Print raster list
             #print rasterList

            # Execute CellStatistics
            TScalar = (TScalar1 * TScalar2)

            #Save the output
            outRasterName = os.path.join(ws_out, "T_SCALAR_{}.tif".format(monthNumber))
            TScalar.save(outRasterName)
            #print outRasterName

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()


    #print done
    #print 'done'
```

Comment: [tag:error-000732] is pretty common so have you reviewed the past Q&As on it?

Comment: I have tried but could no able to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this line `rasterList2 = arcpy.Raster('*Mean_Temp_010.tif')`

It should probably be

```
rasterList2 = arcpy.Raster('*Mean_Temp_{}.tif'.format(monthNumber))
```

It's looping through each folder and can't find `*Mean_Temp_010.tif` in any of them as that file is only in your `OCTOBER` folder (as per your other questions).

If you specifically need the October images, then you either need to make the `010` images available to all folders (include the path to the October image) or copy that image into each folder, something like:

```
rasterList2 = arcpy.Raster(r'D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\OCTOBER\*Mean_Temp_010.tif')
```

Comment: Thank you. i have ran the modified line rasterList2, but still i am getting the same error, file not exist or not supported

Comment: Does it exist? What is the path to that file?

Comment: same path, which you mentioned in your command line

Comment: i copied the path of raster2 direct from folder `D:\SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2\OCTOBER\Mean_Temp_010.tif`

Comment: please suggest me, how do i fix the following error.

Comment: I have faced the same problem last month. Then I checked the input raster. It was missing reference system. I think it is the problem with name. You need to rename the raster path to avoid hypen('-') as SWAT-WEATHER-DATA2 in folder name. I hope it will work this time.